# how to merge two branches with few changes not all

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am working on Visual Studio Code and using git as the VCS , now i have a branch called **X** from this branch i have created another branch called **Y** using command (*git checkout -b Y*) then in **Y** branch i have added some new code as well as made some changes in the previous code.

Now I want to merge **Y** into **X** **only with the changes** not the new code which i have added.

also what are the problems in checking out to the parent branch without commit the changes made in child branch?

Comment: I think you mean Git as a SCV (source control versioning) or SCM (source control management) system.

Comment: So, what question are you asking? Merging `Y -> X` merges changes via a merge stratagy, usually represented by `git diff <ref> <ref>`.

Comment: @benhorgen it is version control system. isn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a `git merge` is the correct process for your situation. You may want to `cherry-pick` a commit or two into the root branch (only those commits that don't include the new files). I suggest this because Git's merge feature is intended to bring the entirety of a branch into another branch.

With that said, it is possible to do `merge` and accomplish your objective. To do so, perform a merge without letting the `merge` process make the `commit`. The result will be a set of changes staged for commit. You can then modify your staged changes (by unstaging the files you don't want merged in) before making the final commit.

Based on your example above you would first checkout branch **X** then:

`git merge Y --no-commit --no-ff`

If it was a clean merge, after the above command you should see a message:

"Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested"

From that point you can unstage any changes you don't want merged in and then perform a `git commmit` with only the desired changes merged in.

Comment: well i want to know that if i am on branch Y with some changes and don’t want these changes to go in branch X and if i checkout to branch X without a commit, will these changes get mixed with the code in X??? if yes then a commit is necessary before checkout to another branch??

Comment: stash your changes... switch branches... do the merge... then switch back to branch 'Y' and pop your stashed changes.